# Electron excitation by photons and electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

I understand that in order for an electron to move to a higher energy level, it must absorb a photon with an exact amount of energy, otherwise the electron will not move.

In an electron discharge tube, in order for an electron to move to a higher energy level, do the colliding electrons need to have *sufficient* energy, rather than an exact amount of energy?

Comment: As far as I konw, energy level only exists when electron is trapped in a potential field, e.g. the Coulomp potential of necleus. In other word, the bounded electron. The electron in an electron discharged tube, however, is free electron and can be described under classic physics.